# Como encontrar os divisores de um número de forma rápida

Tags: c, matemática

Tenho que fazer uma questão que calcule os divisores de números muito grandes e preciso de uma forma rápida sem ser o modo convencional, poderiam me ajudar 
Meu código

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
  int num=19000,i,c=0;
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++)
  {
     if(num%i==0)
     {
        c++;
     }
  }
  printf ("número de divisores e %d,c)

 }
```

Comment: O que é um número "muito grande"? Ou: qual seria o maior número possível para o programa processar?

Comment: O número pode chegar até  10^9

Answer (score 7):

É possível otimizar o *looping* para efetuar o cálculo dos divisores de forma mais eficiente:

- definindo o contador `c` como 2,
- o início do ciclo como 2,
- o final para a raiz quadrada de `num` mais 1 (`sqrt(num)+1`),
- e somando 1 ao contador `c` a cada iteração caso o divisor seja a própria raiz, ou 2 caso não seja.

O *looping* fica dessa forma:

```
c = 2;
for(i=2; i<((int)floor(sqrt(num)))+1; i++)
{
   if(num % i == 0)
   {
      c += (num/i == i) ? 1 : 2;
   }
}
```

Explicando: Para cada divisor `i` menor que a raiz quadrada, existe um recíproco `num/i` maior que a raiz quadrada.

Exemplo: divisores de 64:

```
1
2
4
8   <== raiz quadrada
16  <== recíproco 64/4
32  <== recíproco 64/2
64  <== recíproco 64/1
```

Executando o programa sem otimização para `num=10^10`:

```
Tempo total = 132.3230133580 segundos
número de divisores e 121
```

Com a otimização, o tempo reduz significativamente (também para `num=10^10`):

```
Tempo total = 0.0014944220 segundos
número de divisores e 121
```

---

A explicação para a o aumento no desempenho é a mudança da complexidade de *O(n)* para *O(sqrt(n))*, ou seja, o *looping* vai contar até 100.000 ao invés de 10.000.000.000.

Os tempos foram medidos com a função [clock_gettime()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime).

Segue abaixo, o programa completo utilizado para o teste:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
  struct timespec inicio, fim;
  double demora;
  long long int num=10000000000, i;
  int c;

  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &inicio); // início do cronômetro
#if 0
  // Algoritmo original
  c = 0;
  for(i=1; i<=num; i++)
  {
     if(num%i==0)
     {
        c+=1;
     }
  }
#else
  // Algoritmo otimizado
  c = 2;
  for(i=2; i<((int)floor(sqrt(num)))+1; i++)
  {
     if(num%i==0)
     {
        c += (num/i == i) ? 1 : 2;
     }
  }
#endif
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &fim); // fim do cronômetro
  demora = (fim.tv_sec - inicio.tv_sec) + (fim.tv_nsec - inicio.tv_nsec)/1E9;
  printf("Tempo total = %.10lf segundos\n", demora);
  printf ("número de divisores e %d",c);
}
```

<sub>testado com gcc version 8.1.0 - MinGW-W64</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Fiz deste forma e foi consideravelmente rápido:

```
//Utilizei como teste o seu comentário que o maior número seria 10^9
int number = 1000000000;
int count = 1;
int pow = 0;
int lastDivisor = 2;

for (int i = 2; number > 1; i++)
{
    if (number % i == 0)
    {
        bool isPrime = true;

        //Verifica se o número é primo (caso não seja, não serve para nós)
        for (int j = 2; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isPrime) {
            if (lastDivisor == i) {
                //Enquanto a sequência se repetir (2,2,2), soma mais um no expoente (Ex.: 2³)
                pow++;
            }
            else { //Caso a sequência mude (Ex.: 2,2,2,3), faz o produto dos expoentes.
                count *= (pow + 1);
                lastDivisor = i;
                pow = 1;
            }

            number /= i;
            i = 1;
        }
    }
}
count *= (pow + 1);
printf("%d", count);
```

Utilizei [Decomposição em fatores primos](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~deturck/m170/wk2/numdivisors.html) para conseguir a quantidade de divisores. Caso queira algo "mais rápido", pode tentar implementar o [Crivo de Atkin](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crivo_de_Atkin).